# Does undefined lead to the next item in OR operation?

Tags: jquery, regex, match, string-length

I always thought that a fallback to getting undefined values was to add a disjunction operator with 0 as the second element. Maybe an example is more clear:

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9zucvek/).

```
$("textarea").val().match(/a/g).length || 0)
```

I would expect the above to return the times `a` is found in the textarea, and when it can't be found (and length returns undefined) to skip to the second part of the OR statement, namely `0`. But as you can see this doesn't work. Console returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

So rather than *undefined*, length throws an error. How can I handle this best. How can I make it return `0` when there are no matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns `null` when no match is found. So, when you type something in the `textarea` which does not contain `a`, `match()` will return `null`. And `null.length` is error.

> **Return value**
>
> An Array containing the matched results or **null** if there were no matches.

**Demo**

```js
$("textarea").on("input", function() {
  console.log(($("textarea").val().match(/a/g) || []).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a9zucvek/1/)

You can also use

```
($("textarea").val().match(/a/g) || '').length // Thanks to @nnnnnn
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/a9zucvek/3/)

Comment: You can now remove `|| 0`.

Comment: Would using `... || "").length` be more efficient than creating a new empty array?

Comment: `|| 0` part is redundant now.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I'm interested to know if the comment of @nnnnnn holds true. It seems to me that he is correct.

Comment: @BramVanroy nnnnnn I've also added that

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you explain why?

Comment: I don't *know* that it's more efficient, that's why I asked. I can't be bothered to set up a performance test, but I would guess creating an empty string is quicker than creating an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the result of `.match` is `null`, don't try to get its length!

```
var matches = $("textarea").val().match(/a/g);
var nummatches = matches && matches.length || 0;
```